# Spring Boot conditional schedules

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I know it is possible to run schedules at either a fixed rate, fixed delay or with crons. But how do I deal with this situation:

```
Method A (fixed delay 60 seconds but should never run if B or C is running)
Method B (supposed to run every hour and ALWAYS before C)
Method C (supposed to run 60 seconds after B has finished)
```

How do I set these kind of conditions?

Edit:

I have managed to do this and it seems to work:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10000)
public void A() {
}

@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 60000)
public void BandC() throws InterruptedException {
    MethodB
    Thread.sleep(60000);
    MethodC
}
```

Is this alright or it this way to do it wrong for some reason?

Comment: Please show what you have tried

Comment: I have nothing tried yet because I don't know how. Can I use thread.sleep in a scheduled task? Because then I could just create a sleep between B and C and another sleep after C.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at using a scheduler lock using the `@SchedulerLock` annotation. That would allow you to ensure that only one of A, B, and C are running at once:

https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock

You may have to provide some additional information in your scheduling code to ensure that C is always after B but if the start times for the scheduled tasks are setup right the locking will help enforce that order as well.

Or given the timing conditions you have in place you could just have B schedule C to run once at the termination of B. The locking mechanism plus some thought on where C gets scheduled would probably solve your issue.